# Where does a customer enter coupon code 2checkout?

Tags: coupon, 2checkout

I want to add coupons on my live site but before I do that I am testing the coupons on my sandbox. I have created coupons in the 2checkout admin area. According to the [documentation](http://help.2checkout.com/articles/FAQ/Can-I-offer-coupons/), a customer enters the coupon code after being redirected to the 2checkout site. However, I only see the pop up but i don't see any area to enter coupon code.What gives?

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form" action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><strong>BILLING INFORMATION</strong></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-md-2">Country</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select id="country" class="form-control" name="country" autocomplete="on" required="">
                            <option value="" class="ng-binding">- Choose Country -</option>
                            <option value="USA">United States</option>
                            <option value="GBR">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
                            <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
                            <option disabled="" value="—">—</option>
                            <option value="ALA">Åland Islands</option>
                            <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
                            <option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
                            <option value="ASM">American Samoa</option>
                            <option value="AND">Andorra</option>
                            <option value="AGO">Angola</option>
                            <option value="AIA">Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="ATA">Antarctica</option>
                            <option value="ATG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                            <option value="ARG">Argentina</option>
                            <option value="ARM">Armenia</option>
                            <option value="ABW">Aruba</option>
                            <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
                            <option value="AUT">Austria</option>
                            <option value="AZE">Azerbaijan</option>
                            <option value="BHS">Bahamas</option>
                            <option value="BHR">Bahrain</option>
                            <option value="BGD">Bangladesh</option>
                            <option value="BRB">Barbados</option>
                            <option value="BLR">Belarus</option>
                            <option value="BEL">Belgium</option>
                            <option value="BLZ">Belize</option>
                            <option value="BEN">Benin</option>
                            <option value="BMU">Bermuda</option>
                            <option value="BTN">Bhutan</option>
                            <option value="BOL">Bolivia</option>
                            <option value="BES">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
                            <option value="BIH">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                            <option value="BWA">Botswana</option>
                            <option value="BVT">Bouvet Island</option>
                            <option value="BRA">Brazil</option>
                            <option value="IOT">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                            <option value="BRN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                            <option value="BGR">Bulgaria</option>
                            <option value="BFA">Burkina Faso</option>
                            <option value="BDI">Burundi</option>
                            <option value="KHM">Cambodia</option>
                            <option value="CMR">Cameroon</option>
                            <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
                            <option value="CPV">Cape Verde</option>
                            <option value="CYM">Cayman Islands</option>
                            <option value="CAF">Central African Republic</option>
                            <option value="TCD">Chad</option>
                            <option value="CHL">Chile</option>
                            <option value="CHN">China</option>
                            <option value="CXR">Christmas Island</option>
                            <option value="CCK">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                            <option value="COL">Colombia</option>
                            <option value="COM">Comoros</option>
                            <option value="COG">Congo</option>
                            <option value="COD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
                            <option value="COK">Cook Islands</option>
                            <option value="CRI">Costa Rica</option>
                            <option value="CIV">Cote D'ivoire</option>
                            <option value="HRV">Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
                            <option value="CYP">Cyprus</option>
                            <option value="CZE">Czech Republic</option>
                            <option value="DNK">Denmark</option>
                            <option value="DJI">Djibouti</option>
                            <option value="DMA">Dominica</option>
                            <option value="DOM">Dominican Republic</option>
                            <option value="ECU">Ecuador</option>
                            <option value="EGY">Egypt</option>
                            <option value="SLV">El Salvador</option>
                            <option value="GNQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                            <option value="ERI">Eritrea</option>
                            <option value="EST">Estonia</option>
                            <option value="ETH">Ethiopia</option>
                            <option value="FLK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                            <option value="FRO">Faroe Islands</option>
                            <option value="FJI">Fiji</option>
                            <option value="FIN">Finland</option>
                            <option value="FRA">France</option>
                            <option value="FXX">France, Metropolitan</option>
                            <option value="GUF">French Guiana</option>
                            <option value="PYF">French Polynesia</option>
                            <option value="ATF">French Southern Territories</option>
                            <option value="GAB">Gabon</option>
                            <option value="GMB">Gambia</option>
                            <option value="GEO">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="DEU">Germany</option>
                            <option value="GHA">Ghana</option>
                            <option value="GIB">Gibraltar</option>
                            <option value="GRC">Greece</option>
                            <option value="GRL">Greenland</option>
                            <option value="GRD">Grenada</option>
                            <option value="GLP">Guadeloupe</option>
                            <option value="GUM">Guam</option>
                            <option value="GTM">Guatemala</option>
                            <option value="GGY">Guernsey</option>
                            <option value="GIN">Guinea</option>
                            <option value="GNB">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                            <option value="GUY">Guyana</option>
                            <option value="HTI">Haiti</option>
                            <option value="HMD">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
                            <option value="HND">Honduras</option>
                            <option value="HKG">Hong Kong</option>
                            <option value="HUN">Hungary</option>
                            <option value="ISL">Iceland</option>
                            <option value="IND">India</option>
                            <option value="IDN">Indonesia</option>
                            <option value="IRQ">Iraq</option>
                            <option value="IRL">Ireland</option>
                            <option value="IMN">Isle of Man</option>
                            <option value="ISR">Israel</option>
                            <option value="ITA">Italy</option>
                            <option value="JAM">Jamaica</option>
                            <option value="JPN">Japan</option>
                            <option value="JEY">Jersey</option>
                            <option value="JOR">Jordan</option>
                            <option value="KAZ">Kazakhstan</option>
                            <option value="KEN">Kenya</option>
                            <option value="KIR">Kiribati</option>
                            <option value="KOR">Korea, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="UNK">UNK</option>
                            <option value="KWT">Kuwait</option>
                            <option value="KGZ">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                            <option value="LAO">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                            <option value="LVA">Latvia</option>
                            <option value="LBN">Lebanon</option>
                            <option value="LSO">Lesotho</option>
                            <option value="LBR">Liberia</option>
                            <option value="LBY">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
                            <option value="LIE">Liechtenstein</option>
                            <option value="LTU">Lithuania</option>
                            <option value="LUX">Luxembourg</option>
                            <option value="MAC">Macao</option>
                            <option value="MKD">Macedonia</option>
                            <option value="MDG">Madagascar</option>
                            <option value="MWI">Malawi</option>
                            <option value="MYS">Malaysia</option>
                            <option value="MDV">Maldives</option>
                            <option value="MLI">Mali</option>
                            <option value="MLT">Malta</option>
                            <option value="MHL">Marshall Islands</option>
                            <option value="MTQ">Martinique</option>
                            <option value="MRT">Mauritania</option>
                            <option value="MUS">Mauritius</option>
                            <option value="MYT">Mayotte</option>
                            <option value="MEX">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="FSM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                            <option value="MDA">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="MCO">Monaco</option>
                            <option value="MNG">Mongolia</option>
                            <option value="MNE">Montenegro</option>
                            <option value="MSR">Montserrat</option>
                            <option value="MAR">Morocco</option>
                            <option value="MOZ">Mozambique</option>
                            <option value="MMR">Myanmar</option>
                            <option value="NAM">Namibia</option>
                            <option value="NRU">Nauru</option>
                            <option value="NPL">Nepal</option>
                            <option value="NLD">Netherlands</option>
                            <option value="ANT">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                            <option value="NCL">New Caledonia</option>
                            <option value="NZL">New Zealand</option>
                            <option value="NIC">Nicaragua</option>
                            <option value="NER">Niger</option>
                            <option value="NGA">Nigeria</option>
                            <option value="NIU">Niue</option>
                            <option value="NFK">Norfolk Island</option>
                            <option value="MNP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                            <option value="NOR">Norway</option>
                            <option value="OMN">Oman</option>
                            <option value="PAK">Pakistan</option>
                            <option value="PLW">Palau</option>
                            <option value="PSE">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                            <option value="PAN">Panama</option>
                            <option value="PNG">Papua New Guinea</option>
                            <option value="PRY">Paraguay</option>
                            <option value="PER">Peru</option>
                            <option value="PHL">Philippines</option>
                            <option value="PCN">Pitcairn</option>
                            <option value="POL">Poland</option>
                            <option value="PRT">Portugal</option>
                            <option value="PRI">Puerto Rico</option>
                            <option value="QAT">Qatar</option>
                            <option value="REU">Reunion</option>
                            <option value="ROU">Romania</option>
                            <option value="RUS">Russian Federation</option>
                            <option value="RWA">Rwanda</option>
                            <option value="SHN">Saint Helena</option>
                            <option value="KNA">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                            <option value="LCA">Saint Lucia</option>
                            <option value="SPM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                            <option value="VCT">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                            <option value="WSM">Samoa</option>
                            <option value="SMR">San Marino</option>
                            <option value="STP">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                            <option value="SAU">Saudi Arabia</option>
                            <option value="SEN">Senegal</option>
                            <option value="SRB">Serbia</option>
                            <option value="SCG">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
                            <option value="SYC">Seychelles</option>
                            <option value="SLE">Sierra Leone</option>
                            <option value="SGP">Singapore</option>
                            <option value="SVK">Slovakia</option>
                            <option value="SVN">Slovenia</option>
                            <option value="SLB">Solomon Islands</option>
                            <option value="SOM">Somalia</option>
                            <option value="ZAF">South Africa</option>
                            <option value="SGS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                            <option value="ESP">Spain</option>
                            <option value="LKA">Sri Lanka</option>
                            <option value="SUR">Suriname</option>
                            <option value="SJM">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
                            <option value="SWZ">Swaziland</option>
                            <option value="SWE">Sweden</option>
                            <option value="CHE">Switzerland</option>
                            <option value="TWN">Taiwan</option>
                            <option value="TJK">Tajikistan</option>
                            <option value="TZA">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                            <option value="THA">Thailand</option>
                            <option value="TLS">Timor-Leste</option>
                            <option value="TGO">Togo</option>
                            <option value="TKL">Tokelau</option>
                            <option value="TON">Tonga</option>
                            <option value="TTO">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                            <option value="TUN">Tunisia</option>
                            <option value="TUR">Turkey</option>
                            <option value="TKM">Turkmenistan</option>
                            <option value="TCA">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                            <option value="TUV">Tuvalu</option>
                            <option value="UGA">Uganda</option>
                            <option value="UKR">Ukraine</option>
                            <option value="ARE">United Arab Emirates</option>
                            <option value="GBR">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="USA">United States</option>
                            <option value="UMI">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                            <option value="URY">Uruguay</option>
                            <option value="UZB">Uzbekistan</option>
                            <option value="VUT">Vanuatu</option>
                            <option value="VAT">Vatican City State (Holy See)</option>
                            <option value="VEN">Venezuela</option>
                            <option value="VNM">Viet Nam</option>
                            <option value="VGB">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                            <option value="VIR">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                            <option value="WLF">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
                            <option value="ESH">Western Sahara</option>
                            <option value="YEM">Yemen</option>
                            <option value="YUG">Yugoslavia</option>
                            <option value="ZAR">Zaire</option>
                            <option value="ZMB">Zambia</option>
                            <option value="ZWE">Zimbabwe</option>
                        </select>   
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-md-2">Full Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="card_holder_name" name="card_holder_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required /> 
                    </div>      
                </div>

                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-md-2">Address 1</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="street_address" name="street_address" type="text" placeholder="Address 1" required />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2">Address 2</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="street_address2" name="street_address2" type="text" placeholder="Address 2"/>  
                    </div>      
                </div>

                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-md-2">City</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="City" required />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-md-2">State / Province</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="state" name="state" type="text" placeholder="State/Province" required /> 
                    </div> 
                </div>      

                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-md-2">Postal Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="zip" name="zip" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" required />  
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" required />
                    </div>
                </div><!--form group-->

                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-md-2">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" required />   
                    </div>     
                </div>

                <input type='hidden' name='sid' value='<?php echo TWOCHECKOUT_SELLER_ID;?>' />
                <input type='hidden' name='mode' value='2CO' />
                <input type='hidden' name='li_0_type' value='product' />
                <input type='hidden' name='li_0_name' value='<?php echo $product_name;?>' />
                <input type='hidden' name='li_0_product_id' value='<?php echo $order_id;?>' />
                <input type='hidden' name='li_0_price' value='<?php echo $total;?>' />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Complete Checkout">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using standard checkout instead. It lets the customer add the coupon code in the review cart step